# Can I create a git repository an existing TFS Team Project?

Tags: git, tfs

When my Team project for TFS 2015 was created there was no repository created. Is there any way to create a repository now? If there already exists a repository there is an option 'New repository...' in the Version Control tab in the web-portal but that is missing now.

If I cannot add a repo at this point, I would like to know if I can move the content (User stories and tasks) of this Team Project to another one.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried adding a repo via the web-portal and via Visual Studio.

Comment: That's strange... using any of the default templates a repository should always be created. Try navigating to your Project Settings and adding it from there: `http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PROJECT/_admin/_versioncontrol` your last alternative would be to create one through the REST API. https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/git/repositories#Createarepository

Comment: The option to add the repository from Project Settings was missing. Now that I have the default repository in place the option to add an additional repository is there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, please make sure you have related permission of that Team Project. You can also try to create a repository using **REST API** as *jessehouwing* suggested. Moreover, you can check the logs for troubleshooting which stored in `$:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Temp` and labeled *xxx_TeamProjectCreation_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss.log*.

For the second question, if the two team projects be created using the same process template, the simple solution would be **export the work items to Excel** from old team project and import to new team project.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I managed to create my repo with the tool [TfsGitAdmin](https://github.com/giuliov/TfsGitAdmin) that uses the TFS API.

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of TFS it is possible to add a Git Repo even when "TFVC" was selected during project creation.

On the very top of the (project) page click the "arrow down" on the TFS repo and select the option you wand: Import Git repo, Add git repo, ...